# How can I enhance ImageCompose to blend multiple layers?

Tags: image-processing

Blend modes (or Mixing modes) in digital image editing are used to determine how two layers are blended into each other. Version 8 has functionality to perform binary and basic alpha blending but nothing for the other standard blend modes (ImageCompose only works with two layers).

So the question is:

How can I extend ImageCompose to work with multiple layers with masks in any the standard modes such as Dissolve, Darken, or Soft Light... etc?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would include some example operations with full syntax; I don't have those modes under version7.

Comment: Those modes don't exist, I guess I was asking for them.

Comment: Mike, since this one seemed to emphasize *multiple* layers, and not new blend modes, why don't you post a new question specifically about implementing new [blend modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes)

Comment: Will do, so should I delete this one?

Comment: I don't think you need to; someone may be looking for an answer to *this one*.  Nevertheless it doesn't seem popular so go ahead if you please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you simply `Fold` `ImageCompose` onto a list of pairs of layers and blend modes?

Version 7 doesn't have those advanced blend modes as far as I recall, but a simple example using Alpha:

```
img = ExampleData /@ ExampleData["TestImage"][[25 ;; 27]];

Fold[
 ImageCompose,
 img[[1]],
 {
  {img[[2]], 0.5}, {img[[3]], 0.2}
 }
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Right, I guess I'm just missing the implementations of the different types of blending.

Comment: @Mike perhaps I missed the core of your question.  Does version 8 *have* modes such as "Dissolve, Darken, or Soft Light" in any capacity, or were you asking *how to implement* these?

Comment: That looks very creepy.

Comment: @s0rce yeah, it does. :^)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other standard blend modes could also be realized with the help of these:

- `ImageAdd`
- `ImageSubtract`
- `ImageDifference`
- `ImageMultiply`